# How to fix the lenght of charectors by IF(COUNT())

Tags: php

My code is not working: Is it right to count the values in COMMENTS box?

```
//function to count the entered text in COMMENTS section

function isEligible($comments)
{
  if(count($comments <12 && $comments > 40))
  {
    print "Plz enter the value between 12_40";
    return false;

  }

return true;
}
```

Comment: [strlen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

Comment: what is the type of `$comments` variable - array or string?

Comment: @HankyPanky yes you are right, typo error

Comment: change `count($comments <12 && $comments > 40)` to `strlen($comments) <12 || strlen($comments > 40)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count()` is using for array, so the right syntax should be:

```
<?php
    //function to count the entered text in COMMENTS section
    function isEligible($comments) {
        if (strlen($comments) < 12 || strlen($comments) > 40) {
            print "Plz enter the value between 12 and 40 characters";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
?>
```

Assuming that `$comments` is string.

Comment: Thanks a lot my dear friends.I used 'count' instead of 'strlen'.now it is working...!